# How to type AND in regex word matching

Tags: grep

I'm trying to do a word search with regex and wonder how to type AND for multiple criteria.
For example, how to type the following:
(Start with `a`) AND (Contains `p`) AND (Ends with `e`), such as the word `apple`?

Input

```
apple
pineapple
avocado
```

Code

```
grep -E "regex expression here" input.txt
```

Desired output

```
apple
```

What should the regex expression be?

Comment: `^a.*p.*e$` ? Just "beginning of line, followed by a, zero or more any characters, "p", zero or more chars, e and end of line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't implement `and` in a regexp (but you can implement `then` with `.*`) but you can in a multi-regexp condition using a tool that supports it.

To address the case of `and`s, you should have made your example `starts with a and includes p and includes l and ends with e` with input including `alpine` so it wasn't trivial to express in a regexp by just putting `.*`s in between characters but is trivial in a multi-regexp condition:

```
$ cat file
apple
pineapple
avocado
alpine
```

Using `&&`s will find both words regardless of the order of `p` and `l` as desired:

```
$ awk '/^a/ && /p/ && /l/ && /e$/' file
apple
alpine
```

but, as you can see, you can't just use `.*`s to implement `and`:

```
$ grep '^a.*p.*l.*e$' file
apple
```

If you had to use a single regexp then you'd have to do something like:

```
$ grep -E '^a.*(p.*l|l.*p).*e$' file
apple
alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

two ways you can do it

- all that **`"&&"`** is same as negating the totality of a bunch of OR's **`"||"`**, so you can write the reverse of what you want.
- at a single bit-level, `AND` is same as multiplication of the bits, which means, instead of doing all the `&&` if u think it's overly verbose, you can directly ***"multiply"*** the patterns together :

> ```
> awk '/^a/ * /p/ * /e$/'
> ```

so by multiplying them, you're doing the same as performing multiple logical `AND`s all at once

(but only use the short hand if inputs aren't too gigantic, or when savings from early exit are known to be negligible.

- don't think of them as merely `regex patterns` - it's easier for one to think of anything not inside an action block, what's typically referred to as `pattern`, as

> `any combination and collection of items that could be evaluated for a boolean outcome of TRUE or FALSE in the end`

```
e.g. POSIX-compliant expressions that work in the space include 
     
     sprintf()
     field assignments, etc

     (even decrementing NR - if there's such a need)
```

***but not***

```
      statements like next, print, printf(), 
      delete array etc, or any of the loop structures
```

surprisingly though, ***`getline`*** is directly doable
in the pattern space area (with some wrapper workaround)